# Can't run Selenium script w/ CHROME 81- Error: must have Chrome v 79...that version fails too

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium WebDriver version 3.31 script (Windows 10, CHROME 81) received this error: "***Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit): System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 (SessionNotCreated)***".  I uninstalled that version of CHROME, installed CHROME version 79, verified the version, updated Env PATH with .exe location and restarted the machine and still got the error. Apparently, the CHROME version regressed. Why? How to fix? I even tried a Search on "Sys Config" then went to System Configuration and:
1) Clicked on System tab
2) Scrolled down to Google Update Service - gupdate & Google Update Service - gupdatem and unchecked them
3) Clicked on APPLY...to no avail.
Code is below:
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 0):

Download the chromedriver 81 from here.
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Your browser version and driver version should match.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, but as I mentioned in the first sentence, the error was with CHROME version 81

Answer (score 0):

Update your chrome browser, yjen update chrome usining nugetmanager

Answer (score 0):

From NuGet Package manager you can decrement your chrome driver to version 79.xxxx.xx

Or on Chrome, go to Settings click on about Chrome this updates you browser, then go to nuget package manager chrome driver then update to the relevant version from the drop down list

or When you go to package manager click on the Updates tab the chrome driver should be amongst the packages to update.

I recently had this issue, the way fixed it was as above upgrade chromedriver, but i deleted all my old projects folders so i only had the one project folder, it could be that you have to upgrade all your chrome drivers in all projects.